# Positioning text in css inside a text box (background image)

Tags: html, css, textarea

I am using image in `div` as text box and that image has sort of a border/emboss on it so text goes over that part and it looks bad so i would like to position text cca 15 pixels to the right but whatever i tried doesn’t work

Html:

```
<div id=textarea>
    <h2> Tardis -time music festival </h2>
    <p>
    <br/>    Hello fellow time travelers,
    <br/>    Do you enjoy Music as much as Time travel?
    <br/>    If you do this is the right festival for you!
    <br/>    You don't even have to travel, we come to you,
    <br/>    And take you tot he biggest time adventure of your life!!
    <br/>    experience birth of music, the first rock song and much much more.
    </p>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#textarea{
    background-image:url(images/text.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    border:none;
    width: 910px;
    height:300px;
    color:#CAAA5B;
    padding:3px;
    margin-right:4px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move your div containing your text to the right just use a position shift... Ex:

```
#textarea{
postion:relative;
left:15px;
}
```

This may shift your background image as well but if it does you can add another div that is just the text and does not effect the image in the surrounding div.

```
div id=textarea>
<div id="text">
                <h2> Tardis -time music festival </h2>
        <p>
            <br/>    Hello fellow time travelers,
            <br/>    Do you enjoy Music as much as Time travel?
            <br/>    If you do this is the right festival for you!
            <br/>    You don't even have to travel, we come to you,
            <br/>    And take you tot he biggest time adventure of your life!!
            <br/>    experience birth of music, the first rock song and much much more.
                    </p>
                    </div></div>
```

and

```
<style>
#text{
postion:relative;
left:15px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work , i am fairly convinved that my css has a personality and hates me right now for some reason but i fixed it with padding in whole p tag

Comment: @TrogdoraOresic: Did you try both examples? Also paste your context code into a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ and post the link so I get get a better look at your context code to see what is causing the bug.

Comment: I did try both but it  had absolutely no effect on the code, but i fixed it like this even though it's sorta of a hardcode but it works so i am not gonna even touch it

Comment: @TrogdoraOresic: That is interesting they did not shift the position; but if your positioning works right now there is not need to fix what isn't broken.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try just targeting the elements within the div in your CSS?

```
<style>
#textarea p h2 {
postion:relative;
left:15px;
}
</style>
```